# How do I split Index in segments using latex?

Tags: latex

I continuous sequence of chapters, but I want to divide in segments without changing the number. For example current index as follows.

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2 
Chapter 3 
Chapter 4 
Chapter 5
```

Now let I want Chapter 2 and 3 in one segment while 4 to 5 in other. I want my index to look something like as follows (without changing actual chapter numbers). Also if possible I want to add full page before chapters 2 and 4 to indicate these segments.

```
 Chapter 1
 **--SEGMENT 1----**
 Chapter 2 
 Chapter 3 
**--SEGMENT 2---**
Chapter 4 
Chapter 5
```

Can you tell me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Fauna}
\chapter{Native fauna}
\chapter{Introduced fauna}
\chapter{Extinct fauna}

\part{Flora}
\chapter{Native plants}
\chapter{Invasive plants}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this table of contents: 
[image]

If you want the table of contents to show the "segment" and "chapter" words you can use something like this in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{SEGMENT~}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm}
```